# C# editing xaml files in wpf

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to edit a graphics.xaml file for an application that im working on  using a C# windows form but none of the methods i have tried so far have been working. How can i edit the values insides the property with a specific key?

```
<Style x:Key="PhotoStyle" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Image.Margin" Value="0,10,0,10" />
    <Setter Property="Image.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Image.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Image.MaxWidth" Value="300" />
    <Setter Property="Image.MaxHeight" Value="300" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="IconStyle" TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Image.Margin" Value="0,10,0,10" />
    <Setter Property="Image.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Image.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Image.MaxWidth" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="Image.MaxHeight" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="..\Images\Grant.png" />
</Style>
```

i want to edit the value of the Property="Image.MaxWidth" inside the Key "IconStyle" using values inside a textBox inside my windows form. Thanks in advance !

Comment: I suggest you to use either xml parsing or xaml parsing into your WinForms app.

Comment: @GaurangDave sorry do you have any idea how to do it? I am new to editing it

Comment: xml parsing is very large concept and I will not be able to explain you everything here. I can provide some basic code `var xmlDataDocument = new XmlDocument();xmlDataDocument.PreserveWhitespace = false;xmlDataDocument.Load(YOUR_FILE_PATH);`. You will have to understand [XmlDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.7.2) and also some basic [read](https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/reading-xml-with-the-xmldocument-class/) and [write](https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/writing-xml-with-the-xmldocument-class/) operations.

Comment: Once you try somethig, you can edit your question and put more details such Which xaml files you want to edit OR you want parse any xaml file. Your current question has very less meaningful information.

Comment: @GaurangDave Alright i will try it out thanks alot !